# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character while call ajax with codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter. When I call an ajax request to the page by giving the full path to file, it works fine:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title id='Description'>In this example is demonstrated how to implement server filtering, sorting and paging with jqxGrid.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/jqwidgets-ver3.2.1/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jqwidgets-ver3.2.1/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jqwidgets-ver3.2.1/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jqwidgets-ver3.2.1/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jqwidgets-ver3.2.1/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jqwidgets-ver3.2.1/jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jqwidgets-ver3.2.1/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jqwidgets-ver3.2.1/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jqwidgets-ver3.2.1/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.filter.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jqwidgets-ver3.2.1/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.sort.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jqwidgets-ver3.2.1/jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jqwidgets-ver3.2.1/jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jqwidgets-ver3.2.1/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.pager.js"></script>       
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jqwidgets-ver3.2.1/jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jqwidgets-ver3.2.1/scripts/demos.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // prepare the data
        var source =
        {
            datatype: "json",
            datafields: [
            { name: 'ShipName', type: 'string'},
            { name: 'ShipAddress', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'ShipCity', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'ShipCountry', type: 'string' }
        ],
        cache: false,
        url: 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.4/index.php/blog/controllerfunction',
        filter: function()
        {
            // update the grid and send a request to the server.
            $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('updatebounddata', 'filter');
        },
        sort: function()
        {
            // update the grid and send a request to the server.
            $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('updatebounddata', 'sort');
        },
        root: 'Rows',
        beforeprocessing: function(data)
        {       
            if (data != null)
            {
                source.totalrecords = data[0].TotalRows;                    
            }
        }
        };      
        var dataadapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, {
            loadError: function(xhr, status, error)
            {
                alert(error);
            }
        }
        );

        // initialize jqxGrid
        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
        {       
            source: dataadapter,
            width: "100%",
            filterable: true,
            sortable: true,
            autoheight: true,
            pageable: true,
            virtualmode: true,
            rendergridrows: function(obj)
            {
                return obj.data;    
            },
            columns: [
                { text: 'Ship Name', datafield: 'ShipName'},
                { text: 'Address', datafield: 'ShipAddress'},
                { text: 'City', datafield: 'ShipCity'},
                { text: 'Country', datafield: 'ShipCountry'}
            ]
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body class='default'>
    <h1>Shipment Records</h1>
    <div style="width: 1000px" id="jqxgrid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

works fine with

```
url: 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.4/application/view/serverfiltering_paging_and_sorting_data.php',
```

but

```
url: 'http://server/CodeIgniter_2.1.4/index.php/controllername/controlerfunction',
```

shows an error : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

I did not make any other change in the code.

Comment: The error is saying there is something wrong in the content of the response, so the only way to debug is to look at what shows in that response. Go to the URL that the AJAX is loading in your browser, and save it as a text file or use "View Source" to display it exactly as is. If you can't see what's wrong, edit your question to include the JSON, and the full error message (I'm surprised it doesn't tell you *what* character was unexpected).

Comment: Could be your output has some unwanted characters before the json. You can try doing [ob_clean()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php) to clear the buffer before you output the data.